# Update angular 8 to 13

Tags: angular

New to angular and I am updating someones project from 8.2 to 13.0 but ran into some issues.

have Conflicting peer dependency and even with --force it fails with:
Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.

So when running **ng update** :[image]

and upon running the command **ng update @angular/cdk@9** :[image]

Having this issue with all of the packages and I do not know how to proceed, interpret and fix the error. Would appreciate any help to fix this error.

Comment: Angular has guides on how to do this https://update.angular.io/

Comment: Sometimes you may have some custom library that has been developed for angular 8 and it hasn't been updated to support angular 13. In these cases, the `ng update` command will tell you that there is a problem with the peer dependency. There's not an automatic solution for this problem, you should consider change the dependency or drop it

Answer (score 0):

What commands are you using to do your update?

Angular has some very good documentation that helps you in your process of migrating smoothly between versions.

I send you the direct access to that documentation, then, when you have migrated to version 10, you must do it with version 11 and so on until you reach 12.

https://update.angular.io/?v=9.1-10.0